# No sound from my Windows XP computer

Tags: windows-xp, audio, sound-card

I am not getting any sound from my computer (running Windows XP). I tried to turn up the volume from the start menu but it will not let me do anything. Why is this? I am unsure if I have any sound drivers installed or what is going on. Can you help me?

Comment: How exactly do you turn up the volume from the Start Menu? Do you mean the taskbar?

Comment: Has it ever worked?  Is this a new PC?  When did it stop working?  If it hasn't worked, when and where did you get the PC?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply mean you tried to increase the volume but did not have the controls, it sounds (no pun) to me like as you said, the drivers are not installed.

First things first, if you did have the controls but you meant that it didn't do anything, make sure:

1. Speakers are plugged in to the correct port (Usually the green and/or middle one if there are three, but it can be different).
2. Make sure speakers are plugged in.
3. Make sure speakers work - if you have any known working headphones or other known working speakers, try them.

This is especially true if they have been working in the past but recently suddenly stopped.

Now If the above fails, First check that the drivers are installed:

1. Cick the `Start` Button.
2. Right click `My Computer`.
3. Click `Manage`.
4. Expand `Device Manager` and look for any yellow triangles.

If you see any, it means that something does not have a driver installed. Either look at the website either of the manufacturer of either the system (if off the shelf) or motherboard (if self built or from a small builder).

Alternatively, you may want to look at the audio chip makers website for the driver direct. As there are many, I can't really advise further - but if you give more details of your machine, I can try to find where you need to go.

Lastly, if you have a `Sound Blaster` card, I know that Windows XP (and Windows Update) come with some faulty drivers that cause them to mute after about 5 minutes - go to the [Creative Labs website](http://www.creative.com) and update to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

- Go here to Troubleshoot Sound problems http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307918
- Go to Control Panel , open Sounds and Audio Devices and uncheck mute and try increasing your volume there
- If you Realtek Sound Manager or any there Sound manager , please ensure that sound is not muted there and try increasing volume here also
- Drivers are frequently updated to eliminate bugs or incorporate other changes. To download and install a new or updated driver, follow these steps:

> 1.Connect to the Internet.
>
> 2.Right-click My Computer.
>
> 3.Click Properties.
>
> 4.Click the Device Manager tab.
>
> 5.Click a listed device and a new window will open.
>
> 6.Click Drivers to see what drivers are installed on your computer.
>
> 7.Click Update and Windows will see if you have the latest driver. If not,
>   you can update to the newest version
>   if you wish.